# My Bootstrap 4 responsive column layout not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I made a very simple responsive website layout using Bootstrap 4 so according to the code the no of columns should become 4 when it enters tablet mode ie when the viewport is 768px wide while mine is fine up to 770px showing 4 columns but when it becomes 769px it switches into smartphone mode and take the entire width and stacks on top of each other.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Bootstrap 3, Bootstrap 4 has a bit different [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options). Here `sm` starts to act since <768px. and the `xs` breakpoint now is just `col`. Here, rewritten a bit.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-12" style="background-color:red;">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-12" style="background-color:red;">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-12" style="background-color:red;">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-12" style="background-color:red;">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-12" style="background-color:red;">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-12" style="background-color:red;">
      col
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should prevent the elements from going to fullscreen before the viewport gets even smaller

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">
    col
  </div>
</div>
```

just a reminder for breakpoints, the size(sm/lg) specifies the size of the page that the rule applies to. The rule starts with the smallest size and applies to its size and sizes bigger than it that do not have a rule. The default column size is 12, so that does not need to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

This code will keep only 4 col in the tablet mood and phone mode, but if you want to keep 4 col in pc views too then just remove the col-lg-2 from each class.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-3" style="background-color:red;">
             col
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-3" style="background-color:green;">
             col
        </div><div class="col-lg-2 col-3" style="background-color:pink;">
             col
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-3" style="background-color:yellow;">
             col
        </div><div class="col-lg-2 col-3" style="background-color:white;">
             col
        </div><div class="col-lg-2 col-3" style="background-color:orange;">
             col
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using
`col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12`
classes
if you want same view to mobile devices too just use `col`, like `col-3`. if you want full width for smallest devices use `col-xs-12` it is not important, default is `col-xs-12` you can change it `col-xs-6` something like that.